# React Native: error "Input data should be a String" when using "react-native-markdown-display""

Tags: react-native, input, markdown

I get this error after using React-native-markdown-display package and I don't understand why...
I have only strings in my content database, so it seem's to be something else.

This is the full error:
[folow the link to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58QrV.png)

And my code bellow :

```
    //Libraries
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import GoBackButton from '../components/GoBackButton';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Markdown from 'react-native-markdown-display';

const PostsDetails = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let { selectedPost } = route.params;
        setPost(selectedPost);
        setServices(selectedPost.services);
    }, []);

    console.log(services);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    <GoBackButton onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
                    <Text>{post.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.region}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.category}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.id}</Text>
                    <Markdown>{post.content}</Markdown>
                    <Text>{post.itinerary}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.lat}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.lon}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.price}</Text>
                    <Text>{post.link}</Text>
                    {services.map((service, index) => {
                        return <Text key={index}>{service.attributes.name}</Text>;
                    })}
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
};

export default PostsDetails;
```

I didn't find any similar error in stackOverflow.

Thanks

Comment: Any fix? @sebastien jj

Answer (score 0):

I was using `Docusaurus` when I encountered this error using `markdown-it`. The issue was that Docusaurus has built-in `MDX` support and the module was picking up my markdown files, processed them to `JDX` before they were loaded into my code and that is when the type error occured. I resolved this by simply storing my markdown in `.txt` files, so the module ignores them and they can be loaded as simple strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your object {post.content] is null at times which is quite possible when you're dealing with data. To resolve this add a ternary condition like this

```
                 <Markdown>{post.content ? post.content: ''}</Markdown>
```